# Lower Bound on Norm of Sum of Linearly Independent Vectors in a Banach Space

Tags: banach-spaces

Suppose X is a Banach space and $x_1,...,x_n$ are linearly independent vectors. Can we find some sort of lower bound for $||\sum x_i||$? What about if we restict ourselves to normalised vectors?

Comment: Consider $x_1 = e_1, x_2 = (-e_1 + te_2) / \sqrt{1 + t^2}$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Linear independence does not do anything of consequence here, it's not a quantitative property.

Comment: @Sally Of course, it does. Choose $x_2 = -x_1$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @Tim In user251257's example, let $t\to 0$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp don't spoil it :D